# SQL query to find two rows with a same groupID

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I need to SELECT all rows (*) in my table between rows with records (TIME = 08.38 AND LINE = 28) AND (TIME = 10.20 AND LINE = 28) only if these two rows has the same GROUP_ID (selected rows must have the same GROUP_ID of these two rows).

db_table example with 4 rows:

```
       ID       TIME        LINE        GROUP_ID
        __________________________________________
    A)  1       08.32       28          5
    B)  2       09.18       28          5
    C)  3       10.20       28          5
    D)  4       10.25       28          6
```

In my example the query must return row B) because ordering rows by ID it is between row A) with records (TIME = 08.32 AND LINE = 28) and row C) with records (TIME = 10.20 AND LINE = 28) and it has the same GROUP_ID = 5.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: nothing to do all the thing in a single query

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select * form db_table  
where TIME  between '08.38' AND '10.20' and LINE = 28
group by GROUP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try self join , like :

```
Select * from TestTable T1
Inner Join TestTable T2 On T1.GroupID=T2.GroupID
Where (T1.Time > '08:38:00.0000000' And T1.Time < '10:20:00.0000000')  AND
(T2.Time > '08:38:00.0000000' And T2.Time< '10:20:00.0000000')  AND
T1.Line=28 And T2.Line=28
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful reply, my query should first order by ID (I think) and then select all rows between row A and row C IDs with the same groupID

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully follow what you are after but based on what I think you are after this should work:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    db_table  t1
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Group_ID, Line, MIN(Time) [MinTime], MAX(Time) [MaxTime]
            FROM    db_table 
            GROUP BY Group_ID, Line
        ) t2
            ON t2.Group_ID = t1.Group_ID
            AND t2.Line = t1.Line
WHERE   t1.Time > t2.MinTime
AND     t2.Time < t2.MaxTime
```

I think this canbe performed more efficiently with joins, but since i am not even sure this yields the right results I will hold fire on optimising it.